# a nested route or done as a parameter

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rest

I have the following call:

```
http://localhost:3000/arc/v1/api/menus/51/only_items_with_notes
```

and I'm curious what is the preferred structure of the url - This reads fine and is totally clear what it means. But I am not sure if this is the canonical way to do this. One issue is that it does proliferate the routes.rb file. I have:

```
    get '/menus/:menu_id/only_items_with_notes' => 'api_menus#only_items_with_notes'
```

One think I don't like is that it reads a bit like a pseudo nested attribute. What is the proper, canonical way to do this?

Answer (score 1):

That’s pretty deep nesting. What other routes do you have?

In the absence of more information, I’d suggest that `only_items_with_notes` is really a filter on the functionality of the `index` action. You can use a query parameter to restrict the items to those with notes.

Comment: I might have mis-phrased the question, usually for things like that I do it as just a standard get route and NOT as a nested route. So it is separate from the restful list. A different choice would be to :http://localhost:3000/arc/v1/api/menus/51?type=only_items_with_notes but that seems really ugly

Comment: You think having `only_items_with_notes` as part of the path *isn’t* ugly? I’d use a more terse parameter, such as `filter=notes`.

Comment: It's a complex app so I actually think `only_items_with_notes` is ok. That being said - that's why I'm asking the question.

Comment: uhh... well, maybe the answer is that it's just a lot of info coming back due to being a complex app - just not sure what the Rails restful canonical way to doing this is